# Execute gcloud commands in a bash script

Tags: bash, gcloud

`gcloud init` command doesn't offer login prompt during a bash script execution.

But it offered the login after I typed `exit` command manually after script ended.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ exit
logout
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Settings from your current configuration [default] are:
Your active configuration is: [default]


Pick configuration to use:
 [1] Re-initialize this configuration [default] with new settings 
 [2] Create a new configuration
Please enter your numeric choice:  1

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

To continue, you must log in. Would you like to log in (Y/n)?
```

My bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OS=`cat /proc/version`

function setupGCE() {
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
`exec -l $SHELL`
`gcloud init --console-only`
`chown -R $USER:$USER ~/`
}


if [[ $OS == *"Ubuntu"* || $OS == *"Debian"*  ]]
then
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-pip python-dev curl
sudo pip install apache-libcloud
setupGCE
fi
```

How can I get the login prompt during the bash script execution?

Comment: Each backtick-ed command runs in its own shell. So they don't interact (specifically whatever `gcloud init --console-only` does will not affect any later shells). Additionally the backticks are just wrong here. They run the inner command and then try to run the *output* from those commands as commands.

Comment: @EtanReisner what do you propose? To place all commands in a single backtick-ed command? Like, backtick`exec -l $SHELL && gcloud init --console-only && chown -R $USER:$USER ~/`backtick ?

Comment: No, you don't need backticks here at all. They are just wrong... unless `gcloud init --console-only` spits out lines that you need the current shell to run in which case you may want `eval \`gcloud init --console-only\`` but I don't know that it does that. You just want to run those commands in your current shell. So just write them like normal commands. And don't run a new shell (that you then need to `exit`) since you don't want a new shell session.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ok, I've got it. Thank you. Create an answer and I will vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the posted snippet.

The correct snippet is (probably):

```
function setupGCE() {
    curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
    gcloud init --console-only
    chown -R $USER:$USER ~/
}
```

The first error with the original, which you discovered yourself (the what of it at least it not the why), is that `exec -l $SHELL` is blocking progress. It does that because you've run an interactive shell that is now waiting on you for input and the function is waiting for that process to exit before continuing.

Additionally, `exec` replaces the current process with the spawned process. You got lucky here actually. Had you not wrapped the call to `exec` in single quotes your function would have exited the shell script entirely when you exited the `$SHELL` it launched. As it is, however, `exec` just replaced the sub-shell that the backticks added and so you were left with a child process that could safely exit and return you to the parent/main script.

The second issue is that backticks run the command they surround and then replace themselves with the output. This is why

```
echo "bar `echo foo` baz"
```

outputs `bar foo baz`, etc. (Run `set -x` before running that to see what commands are actually being run.) So when you write

```
`gcloud init --console-only`
```

what you are saying is "run `gcloud init --console-only` then take its output and replace the command with that" which will then attempt to run the output as a command itself (which is likely not what you wanted). Similarly on the other lines.

This happens to not have been problematic here though as `chown` and likely `gcloud init` don't return anything and so the resulting command line is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the `exec -l $SHELL` did all the mess. I changed it to `source ~/.bashrc` and now it works.